# Laravel 5.7 and ExtJS 5 app configuration

Tags: laravel, extjs

I am trying for the first time to create an application with **Laravel 5.7** and ExtJS 5.

There is a lot of information for Laravel / Vue and Laravel / Angular applications, but for Laravel / ExtJS it is practically non-existent (unfortunately).

I created an ExtJS app called extjs_app with cmd that I put in the *public* folder of the Laravel project.

In the Laravel *views* folder I created a view named index_extjs.blade.php containing the index.html code of the ExtJS app with the following change:

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

replaced for

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="extjs_app/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

And in the bootstrap.js file (I probably should not edit this file):

```
Ext.manifest = Ext.manifest || "bootstrap.json";
```

replaced for

```
Ext.manifest = Ext.manifest || "extjs_app / bootstrap.json"
```

And in the app.json file

```
indexHtmlPath": "index.html"
```

replaced for

```
"indexHtmlPath": "../../../resources/views/index_extjs.php"
```

However, despite several attempts, the files required for the ExtJS application are not loaded.

How to properly configure Laravel and ExtJS to work together?

[image]

Comment: Try reverting back to `indexHtmlPath": "index.html"`

Comment: Thanks Nikola. I made the change and I get the same result. Still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the root route for the entire application to be served with your `blade` view, in your case `index_extjs.blade.php`.

Why? Because when anyone opens up your site, you are loading up that page and hence, loading `extjs` too. After that page is loaded, you can handle page changes through extjs.

So to achieve this, you need to declare your root route to server this index file:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('index_extjs');
});
```

Also you need to revert all `extjs` config changes back to default, because everything will be relative to your `extjs` app inside `public` folder and not relative to the project itself. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I have a login before loading the application. The problem was in the redirectTo configurations. Thanks for the help and for indicating the correct course to follow to solve this question.